# RJ45 dual LED green and yellow operating

Tags: usb, ethernet, rj45

Attached is a small section of USB to Ethernet converter design. RJ 45 Connector has one dual LED (see attached) Green and Yellow, backward connected, and drive via the LAN9500 chip pin27. 
[image]

As per design look like only Green LED will trun on when nLNKA_LED/GIO9 goes low. and when nLNKA_LED/GIO9 goes high no LED will turn on. then how the yellow LED will turn on here?

Comment: You have forgotten to tell us what the LEDs are supposed to indicate. For example, if the 3.3 V falls to zero it might light and indicate a PSU fault. Put the information into the question. What is the supply voltage on the LAN9500?

Comment: supply voltage is 3.3V, This pin is driven low (LED on) when a valid link is
detected. This pin is pulsed high (LED off) for
80 mS whenever transmit or receive activity is
detected. This pin is then driven low again for a
minimum of 80 mS, after which time it will repeat
the process if TX or RX activity is detected.
Effectively, LED2 is activated solid for a link. When
transmit or receive activity is sensed, LED2 will
function as an activity indicator.

Comment: All that information belongs in the question as I suggested so that the readers don't have to trawl through the comments to find all the relevant info.

Comment: link of design is http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/9500ai_sch.pdf

Comment: I give up .....

Comment: @Transistor why do you give up?

Comment: @MatsK: Because OP has twice added relevant information in the comments instead of in the question. Read the comment history.

Comment: @Transistor Ok, I see what you refer to.

Answer (score 2):

It won't ever turn on. The supply for the chip is 3.3V so the output will be either 0V or 3.3V. It's effectively the same as if the yellow LED die was not present.

Still better than an eval board I have which has the link LED connected to the power supply through a resistor. You can plug a pencil into the jack and the light still turns on when power is applied.

Comment: Looks like you got fault eval board

Comment: @ShortCircuit The board faithfully follows the OrCAD schematic, so it's the design that's questionable.

Answer (score 1):

The schema doesn't make sense, from what I have seen as common practice.

The only way I can think of is that "nLNKA_LED/GPIO9" is either 0 volt or 6,6 volt. That way the current will either flow through the green or the yellow LED.

A common practice when you have two LED's in opposing directions, you normally have two I/O pin connected to either side.

This way you can have either the green or the yellow lit with just two wires.

The way you do it is:

```
Pin 9  Pin 10   LED lit
  0      0      No light
  1      0      Green
  0      1      Yellow
  1      1      No light
```

Comment: Reference design show only one Io connected to this LED's. http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/9500ai_sch.pdf

Comment: Mmmm and then  one of the LED's (Yellow) will newer produce light! as @Spehro Pefhany answered.

Comment: Oops there is a way!!! If the status (voltage level) on "nLNKA_LED/GPIO9" can be either 0volt or + 6,6volt, then will either the green or yellow light up. I will adjust my reply accordingly.